# WPF TreeView: how to add a trigger for all tree elements

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, triggers, binding

The right side of the window contains data, when you drag it to the left, the color of these items turns gray. I have a button that needs to hide gray elements.

[Image: The data is highlighted in gray, the hide button is disabled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwn4W.png)

[Image: The data is highlighted in gray, the hide button is enable, the item is hidden.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6uRm.png)

But, if I drag the inner treeviewitem, nothing happens

[Image: Inner element is dragged, the hide button is disable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9Ubk.png)

[Image: Inner element is dragged, the hide button is enable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJF0o.png)

How can you change the code so that triggers apply to all elements?

TreeView XAML:

```
 <TreeView
                Grid.Column="2"
                x:Name="RevitCategories">
                <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style
                        TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                        <EventSetter
                            Event="DragOver"
                            Handler="RevitCategories_OnDragOver" />
                        <EventSetter
                            Event="MouseMove"
                            Handler="RevitCategories_OnMouseMove" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition
                                        Binding="{Binding Path=ShowUsages, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        Value="False" />
                                    <Condition
                                        Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Foreground,
                                        Converter={vm:ColorToHiddenConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        Value="False" />
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter
                                    Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Collapsed" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock
                            FontSize="{DynamicResource MediumFontSize}"
                            FontFamily="{DynamicResource FontFamily}" />
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeView>
```

Converter:

```
public class ColorToHiddenConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var brush = (Brush) value;
        var colorSample = Colors.Gray;
        return brush.Equal(colorSample);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture) => null;

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => this;
}
```

Comment: Add RelativeSource and specify the class containing ShowUsages property OR add ElementName and refer it to the CheckBox (give a CheckBox a name)
<Condition Binding="{Binding Path=ShowUsages, ElementName=CheckBoxName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False" />

Comment: @gadnandev there are no problems with binding to the checkbox, there is a problem with binding to the foreground property for non-root treeviewitem

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I changed </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle> to <TreeView.Resources> and it worked