# WPF: TreeViewItem dataTrigger

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

How can I change the color of the TreeViewItem to gray when that color of all child TreeViewItems is also gray?
my code only works when the tree is initialized for the first time, and does not work when the program continues to work.
[image]

Code:

```
<DataTrigger
    Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self},Converter={vm:TreeViewItemsGrayConverter}}"
    Value="True">
    <Setter
        Property="Foreground"
        Value="Gray" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var treeViewItems = (TreeViewItem) value;
    if (treeViewItems == null) return false;
    return treeViewItems.Items.Count != 0 && treeViewItems.Items.Cast<TreeViewItem>()
                                                          .All(item => item.Foreground.Equal(Colors.Gray));
}
```

**Edit:** at the moment I have not found a way to do this using a binding and wrote a code like this

```
private bool CheckContainerVisibility(TreeViewItem container)
{
    var grayChild = 0;
    foreach (TreeViewItem item in container.Items)
        if (item.Foreground.Equal(_viewModel.HiddenColor))
            grayChild++;
        else if (!item.Items.IsEmpty)
            if (CheckContainerVisibility(item))
                grayChild++;

    if (container.Items.Count != grayChild) return false;
    container.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(_viewModel.HiddenColor);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What determines if an item is _gray_ to start with? Is there any property in your model?

Comment: @thatguy see screenshots in this post, i am using drag and drop https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66585313/wpf-treeview-how-to-add-a-trigger-for-all-tree-elements